# Problemas con liquorix

Tags: linux, interfaz-gráfica

Instalé liquorix como kernel de lubuntu para mejorar el rendimiento del equipo en tareas que requirieran procesamiento de gráficos, cómo simuladores o juegos, el problema es que se ven líneas cómo glitches cuando un objeto gráfico se encuentra detrás de otro, ¿cómo puedo resolver este problema?

Detalles del equipo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hm, en la documentación no mencionan este tipo de inconvenientes? Será que debes cambiar el driver de video?

Comment: ¿Tiene el mismo problema con un kernel que no es liquorix? ¿O con una versión diferente del grano de liquorix? ¿Qué versión de mesa está ejecutando? El kernel 5.11 tuvo cambios significativos en los controladores de gráficos de Intel (por lo que puede requerir una actualización de mesa a 21.1). Nota: estos son solo consejos generales para la resolución de problemas: no soy un experto en gráficos y especialmente no en gráficos Intel o mesa (principalmente uso GPU nvidia con el controlador propietario de nvidia, que no usa mesa)

Comment: @Alfabravo , en la documentación no se mencionan este tipo de problemas, revisé el repositorio en github y no parece que se presente esto, los drivers los actualicé así que no creo que sea eso

Comment: @JohnDoe , puede que esa sea la respuesta al problema, ya que al ver la versión del kernel con "uname -a" aparece "Linux moro-system 5.11.0-16.1-liquorix-amd64 #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT liquorix 5.11-30ubuntu1~groovy (2021-04-21) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux", como puedo actualizar a la nueva versión?

Comment: @MizraimMoroyoqui Actualizar a una versión preliminar de Mesa (o cualquier otra, en realidad) puede ser complicado, no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo en lubuntu. En debian, buscaría en los backports, o tal vez con **mucho cuidado** trataría de instalar paquetes seleccionados de inestable o experimental; esto puede provocar un verdadero desastre o un sistema roto, que definitivamente no se recomienda. La mejor opción sea degradar a un kernel de liquorix 5.10, que no debería necesitar una nueva Mesa.

Comment: @MizraimMoroyoqui Por cierto, solía ejecutar núcleos de licorix en Debian hace años. En mi opinión, los beneficios de rendimiento/capacidad de respuesta promocionados son exagerados y sobrevalorados. Para su información, para ver qué versiones, por ejemplo, libgl1-mesa-dri tiene instaladas o disponibles, ejecute `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri.` Como dije anteriormente, no recomendaría intentar actualizar a versiones preliminares. Es mejor degradar su kernel y esperar una actualización de los paquetes de lubuntu. Con ubuntu, faltan menos de 6 meses hasta el lanzamiento de 2110.